# Idris module name collision with 'base'

Tags: scope, idris

I have a module whose name ends with  `Data.List`.
Inside it i want to import module `Data.List` from the base library.

```
module Foo.Data.List
import Data.List
```

If i invoke idris from folder `Foo` then compiler complains:

```
[Foo]$ idris --check Data/List.idr
Cycle detected in imports: Data/List.idr -> Data/List -> Data/List
```

I guess because it prefers the module being in the current source folder, that is the module just being defined.

How can i refer to the one `Data.List` which is in the base library?

My little source file in its full:

```
module Foo.Data.List
import Data.List as S

last : List e -> Maybe e
last l = case l of
    (h::t) => Just (S.last (h::t))
    _ => Nothing
```

**Updated:**

If i invoke idris from the folder containing `Foo`,

```
idris --check Foo/Data.List.idr
```

then I get the error message:

```
When checking right hand side of Foo.Data.List.case block in last at ./Foo/Data/List.idr:6:15 with expected type
        Maybe e

When checking argument x to constructor Prelude.Maybe.Just:
        Type mismatch between
                Maybe e (Type of last (h :: t))
        and
                e (Expected type)
```

Which implies that the compiler considers `S.last` as `Foo.Data.List.last` instead of `base.Data.List.last`.

Comment: i am using 0.10.0 as released on Cabal.

Answer (score 0):

Given the following directory structure:

```
[idris-stuff]$ tree
.
└── myproject
    └── Foo
        └── Data
            └── List.idr
```

you will need to run `idris` in the `myproject` directory, not `myproject/Foo`:

```
[idris-stuff]$ cd myproject
[myproject]$ idris --check Foo/Data/List.idr
```

If you try to run it from `Foo`, it will fail because your local `Data/List.idr` file will be picked over the standard library one:

```
[myproject]$ cd Foo/
[Foo]$ idris --check Data/List.idr
Cycle detected in imports: Data/List.idr -> Data/List -> Data/List
```

Comment: What would be a solution is for example ability to refer to standard lib with a unique path prefix, like "base".

Comment: It will not pick `Foo.Data.list` when you `import Data.List` in your other modules, unless you mistakenly try to compile those other modules from inside `Foo` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your second problem is caused simply by the fact that `S.last` is not in scope, since there is no definition with the name `Data.List.last`. The error message you get is very confusing and might be worth reporting as an Idris bug; a much better error message would be one that complains about `S.last` not being in scope.

To wit, the following version typechecks and works as expected:

```
module Foo.Data.List
import Prelude.List as S

last : List e -> Maybe e
last l = case l of
    (h :: t) => Just (S.last (h::t))
    _ => Nothing
```

Comment: It does not matter if base/Data.Last.last exists or not. The compiler does find S.last as Foo.Data.List.last - this of course leads to type error. The problem is that S = Foo.Data.List instead of base/Data.List.